# php facebook graph api query with access_token

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an android app where the user authenticates with facebook. Now, i make a post request to my server and i sent the access_token of facebook to this server. On the server, i now want to access user informations by just passing the access_token to the facebook graph api. Is there any solution to do so? The problem is that the user just uses the app and the webserver has to authenticate just with the access_token. Thanks!

Comment: Of course this is possible – the API does not care where an access token is coming from, as long as its valid.

Comment: So how would i do this in php, this was my question. Sorry.

Comment: You already have the access_token, why not use the Graph API to get the user information?

Comment: Yes, i have the access_token. I've searched a long time to find a proper solution but i can't find out how to make the request to the graph api via php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - it's actually very "simple" (as far as Facebook goes).

To take you through the steps:

1. Set up: In Facebok Developer apps, make sure you have set both the mobile (Android) and website settings for the same app. They need to share the App ID and secret
2. Set up: Download the [PHP SDK for Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/). This makes it much simpler that fighting the the raw "Graph" calls.
3. Process: When the user logs in on your mobile, you get the "Access Token". This the the item you want to pass to your PHP server.
4. Process: In PHP, when you initialize your Facebook class, tell it not to use cookies.
5. Process: In PHP, after initialising the class, use the `SetAccessToken` function from the SDK to use the access token you got in your mobile app.
6. Process: Then, when you do `/me` calls, you will be the same user that acquired the token on mobile.

Code sample:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  cookie : false
));

// Use the token you sent
$facebook->setAccessToken($sentToken);

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, step 5 helped me to go on!